# Is there a formal way of saying 'hog'?

Tags: single-word-requests, formality, register

The term **hog**, as defined below, is an informal word.

> 1.3 *informal* A greedy person.
>
> *‘Our King was, in a simple statement, a greedy, power-hungry covetous hog.’*

([Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hog))

Obligatory SWR example sentence:

How would Brenda (Queen Elizabeth II) say 'hog'?

> Phillip! You're [hogging] all of one's bed!

My example is a bit tongue-in-cheek but I would prefer something one could say naturally; it doesn't have to be in Royal English.
Is there a formal word for this?

Comment: *My dear Phillip, must you be so cupidinous of the covers?*

Comment: *Gourmand* is a term for someone who eats like a pig.

Comment: For other terms consult a thesaurus, using one of the words below as a key.

Comment: Greedy or a piggy.

Comment: Do you have a preference for part-of-speech? Your example sentence suggests a verb, but most people who only see the title will think of a noun. Of the current answers, one is a verb, one a noun, and one an adjective.

Comment: @suməlic No particular preference, no. I am happy even with some sort of rephrasing as aparente001 has done.

Answer (score 5):

How about *monopolize*?

From M-W:

> [*monopolize*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/monopolize):
>   to get a monopoly of : assume complete possession or control of
>
> [*monopolist*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/monopolist):
>   a person who monopolizes
>
> [*monopoly*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/monopoly):
>   exclusive possession or control

Your example:

> Phillip! You're *monopolizing* the bed!

I can easily imagine Brenda (Queen Elizabeth II) saying this.

Comment: This is quite good and I saw it when researching a definition. However, I don't think it fits so well in a normal sentence.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey Thanks. It has it's uses, e.g., *monopolize* a conversation.

Answer (score 2):

***[Covetous](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/covetous?s=t)*** (adj.) could do.

> 1. inordinately or wrongly desirous of wealth or possessions; greedy.
> 2. eagerly desirous.

*from* Dictionary.com

This word is an adjective. If you need a noun, use ***covetous person***.

I noticed after posting that this word was used in the OP's example sentence as "covetous hog". In a sense, the phrase "covetous hog" is, to some degree, a tautology, since a hog is covetous and a covetous person is often a hog.

Another word is ***[Acquisitive](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/acquisitive)*** (adj.) (found using a Google search for "synonyms for greedy"). Here is Dictionary.com's definition:

> 1. tending or seeking to acquire and own, often greedily; eager to get wealth, possessions, etc.:

*from* Dictionary.com

This word seems to imply more of the *action* involved in being a hog. A covetous person might not actually acquire any of whatever it is that they covet, while an acquisitive person might be a covetous person who is *actually doing so*.

Comment: Could you please use more of [your own words](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/9603/2085) so it’s a real answer?

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what you are looking for? I acknowledged and cited the source I am using for the definition. The idea to choose the word was my own work - I am relying on the citation only as proof of the definition.

Comment: Thank you for that.  We’re trying to build up a library of expert answers, and these single-word requests are a problem if they don’t do that.

Comment: You're welcome. I have expanded my answer with more analysis of my own doing.

Answer (score 1):

***[Glutton](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/glutton)***  is a more formal term and is used to suggest the idea of greed and and sheer desire to do something that you are referring to:

> - a person with a remarkably great desire or capacity for something:
>   *a glutton for work; a glutton for power*.

Dictionary.com

Comment: Gluttony implies some sort of greed, in my experience. Also, it doesn't imply that they are taking up most of something, think about 'road hog'

Comment: Could you please use more of [your own words](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/9603/2085) so it’s a real answer?

Comment: @tchrist - are you saying that my answer, as it stands, is an instance of plagiarism?

Comment: Thank you for editing to add some of your own words. I’m saying that an answer that is nothing but copypasta from a General Reference is ***AT BEST*** very low quality and quite possibly not even an answer at all by site standards. Because **answers should be mostly your own words, *not copypasta,*** such minor contributions may wind up being flagged as Very Low Quality or Not an Answer and eventually deleted. If there are several of these, it probably means the question should be closed as Too Broad or Off Topic. [elu.se] is not a copypasta service or a guessing game.

Answer (score 1):

If a phrase will do...

> Phillip! You're taking all the covers for yourself!